# Adapter nevers enter the getView method

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-adapter

I have a tab application with a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="3dp">
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent"
           />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I want to call a `ListView` screen it, so  I designed like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the gridview look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and I call the adapter using:

```
SectionsAdapter adapter = new SectionsAdapter(Sections.this ,R.layout.sectionviewgridview,
                            appState.MainCategories);
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and the adapter looks like:

```
public class SectionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mainCategories;

    private final Context context;

    public SectionsAdapter(Context context, int  ResourceId,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items)
    {
        super(context, ResourceId);
         this.context = context;
         this.mainCategories = items ;

         Log.d("The count of the hash is",""+items.size()); 

    }

     @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

{

        Log.d("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","I'm hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" );


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sectionviewgridview, parent, false);

         ImageView ImageViewObject = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewContent);



         try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new java.net.URL(mainCategories.get(position).get("imageUrl")).getContent());
                 ImageViewObject.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",mainCategories.get(position).get("name"));

         TextView TextViewObject = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryName);

         TextViewObject.setText(mainCategories.get(position).get("name"));

        return rowView;




}

}
```

It never logs what's in the `getView` method. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your extension of `ArrayAdapter` calls back to the super class with `super(context, ResourceId);` then you have to make sure to override the `getCount` method to return the exact data size, otherwise, the adapter will not know that you want to use the `mainCategories` as the underlining data and will create a `List` with the size `0` and the `getView` method will not be called. I don't know exactly how you plan to use that `ArrayList` of `Maps` but try to add this to your `SectionedAdapter`:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
     return mainCategories.size();
}
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then add more details about what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue..

My Layout:

ListView defined in a Relativelayout and the contents of listview are two textviews defined in one more Relativelayout.

Issue:

The two textviews width was mentioned as 0dp, because of this the position of getview is 0 with no content displayed.

Resolved:

Resolved by providing the width of two textviews to wrap_content.